# HR telling my manager about an interview

Tags: interviewing, job-change, human-resources

I have an interview for a company that has an agreement with my company not to take client's but I am only an apprentice. If the company the interview is with ask permission from my company's HR department to interview me ect. Is my HR allowed to inform my department manager of this interview, even before I have the interview or accepted a job?

Comment: This question is [off-topic](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2694#2694) for this site. Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: yes, they almost certainly can. Human Resources employees are employees of the company - they work for the company and are expected to do what's best for the company, regardless of what effect this may have on you. It's a common myth that HR is there to advocate for employees somehow - I don't know why that myth is so popular.

Without some special confidentiality agreement signed by them and you, companies are allowed to talk to each other about job applicants, HR departments are allowed to talk to managers, etc. Job applications and employment is not legally protected data in any legal area of the world I'm familiar with, but of course you'd need to talk with a legal expert in your area to confirm this.